# Visual Studio - Cannot start ASP.NET Core project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Last few months I create console applications with .NET framework and C#. 
Now I want to create ASP.NET Core MVC projects, but I cannot choose any .NET Core template.

If I click "Console App (.NET Core)" or "ASP.NET Core Web Application" or any other .NET Core template, I can see this error message:

[image]

So, the problem occurs if I choose "Core", other templates work fine.
I have already tried to find a solution on Google.

What could be the problem? I reinstalled VS few times but did not help.

[image]

Comment: Just guessing: Have you tried to execute Visual Studio as administrator? (cause of the access denied message)

Comment: @RalfBönning Yes, I have already tried it.

Comment: Can you run `dotnet --version` in the console? Are you sure you've installed dotnet core SDK without error or warning?

Comment: @User987 I meant can you run that command in cmd? If you can, what you get? If that works try creating a new template with CLI here's a link to it's guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new?tabs=netcore2x

Answer (score 0):

.NET Core does not support COM. COM is a Windows-only thing, and everything in Core is cross-platform. You must run on the full framework if you need to utilize a COM library.

That said, Microsoft has recently release a [preview NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility/2.0.0-preview1-25914-04) with some Windows compatibility APIs. This *may* allow you to utilize COM; I haven't tried it. However, the stated purpose of the NuGet is to make it easier to migrate existing .NET Framework applications to .NET Standard/.NET Core, so it's not considered something you would continue to utilize long-term. Rather, the idea is that you would actively work to migrate code that is not compatible to equivalent .NET Standard/.NET Core APIs, and then eventually remove the package entirely. As a result, it's probably not a good idea to go this route, even if it does enable you to use the COM library, simply because you're not likely to be able to stop at some point in the future.

Long and short, just run on the full framework.

Comment: But what is the problem, something is wrong with my system? If Core is cross-platform, why can't I start any template?